# Assets not compailing on development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, development-environment

I have a ROR app and i am trying to improve performance by loading the asset pipeline.

on my layout file i am calling

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'users/application_login', :media => "all"
```

When i run it in development it works perfect

```
ss
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
=> Debugger enabled
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

but when i run it as production it tells me that my assets are not precompiled

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-25 13:52:18 -0400
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered users/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/login (539.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 860ms
** [Airbrake] Success: Net::HTTPOK

ActionView::Template::Error (users/application_login.css isn't precompiled):
```

i am running

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

and i see some files on **/public/assets/users/** but not **application_login.css**

What can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### in production.rb add:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( application_login.css )
```

Comment: you can add any other missing files there as well